# webview loads again when touching notification

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I am using webview to show a chatbox from my website. And i am building a notification when new message is typed in that chatbox. But when i touch the notification,even if i am currently in that intent which runs webview, it loads page again.
How can i prevent that?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
private static final int unid = 6546468;
notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            notification.setAutoCancel(true);
            notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
            notification.setTicker(nickname + " : " + message);
            notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
            notification.setContentTitle(nickname);
            notification.setContentText(message);
            notification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
            Intent shoutbox = new Intent(this, Shoutbox.class);
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
                  PendingIntent pshoutbox = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, randomInt, shoutbox, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            notification.setContentIntent(pshoutbox);
            notification.setLights(Color.BLUE, 1500, 500);
            long[] pattern = {500,500};
             NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nm.notify(unid, notification.build());
```

Comment: Have you tried making your activity `singletop`?

Comment: I tried it now, thanks. Now it's not loading everytime.

Comment: Can I leave it as an answer?

Comment: yes, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in your manifest. This is because you do not want to create a new activity when it is on top.

Note: If your webview activity is not on top and you click on the notification you may get two instances of activity.